# get face skin tone color from image

Tags: android, colors

i have tried below code that is returning me color of specific pixel which i have pass in argument

```
int x = (int)event.getX();
int y = (int)event.getY();
int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);


int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);   

int[] color={redValue ,blueValue ,greenValue };
btn.setBackgroundColor(getHexColor(color));


public static int getHexColor(int[] color) {
return android.graphics.Color.rgb(color[0], color[1], color[2]);
}
```

i have also try color palette following link is reference link that is also not returning perfect skin tone color of face

[this is i have also tried](https://developer.android.com/training/material/palette-colors.html)

anyone have idea how to extract or get face skin tone color ??

Comment: show your color pallete code

Comment: https://medium.com/david-developer/extracting-colors-from-images-integrating-picasso-and-palette-b9ba45c9c418
Try this. use pallete with picasso. if it helps you then let me know

Comment: Palette palette = Palette.generate(bitmap);
int default = 0x000000;
int vibrant = palette.getVibrantColor(default);
int vibrantLight = palette.getLightVibrantColor(default);
int vibrantDark = palette.getDarkVibrantColor(default);
int muted = palette.getMutedColor(default);
int mutedLight = palette.getLightMutedColor(default);
int mutedDark = palette.getDarkMutedColor(default);

Comment: Please check this one:- http://www.truiton.com/2015/05/android-palette-pick-colors-images/

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for getting colors from images.
You can follow this tutorial for further information.

https://medium.com/david-developer/extracting-colors-from-images-integrating-picasso-and-palette-b9ba45c9c418

```
 Palette.from(bitmap)
            .generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
                    Palette.Swatch textSwatch = palette.getVibrantSwatch();
                    if (textSwatch == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Null swatch :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                }
                backgroundGroup.setBackgroundColor(textSwatch.getRgb());
                titleColorText.setTextColor(textSwatch.getTitleTextColor());
                bodyColorText.setTextColor(textSwatch.getBodyTextColor());
            }
        });
```

Comment: image is not loading in picasso dont know what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
Matrix inverse = new Matrix();
                    v.getMatrix().invert(inverse);
                    float[] touchPoint = new float[] {event.getX(), event.getY()};
                    inverse.mapPoints(touchPoint);
                    int xCoord = (int) touchPoint[0];
                    int yCoord = (int) touchPoint[1];
                    int intColor = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap().getPixel(xCoord,yCoord);


btn.setBackgroundColor(intColor);
```

Hope This will help

OR

Simply Change this in you code, don't convert the color pixel to hex.
Use the color pixel directly in setBackGroundColor(pixel) 
like

```
btn.setBackgroundColor(pixel);
```

This is the full code i have tried

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction()==(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)){

            Matrix inverse = new Matrix();
            v.getMatrix().invert(inverse);
            float[] touchPoint = new float[] {event.getX(), event.getY()};
            inverse.mapPoints(touchPoint);
            int xCoord = (int) touchPoint[0];
            int yCoord = (int) touchPoint[1];
            int intColor = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap().getPixel(xCoord ,yCoord );


            try {
                btn.setBackgroundColor(intColor);
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Try catch is not necessary but i am putting it only for precaution for any unplanned error

Comment: hello @RajatN what is v obj ??

Comment: Its View Object, in onTouch function onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)

Comment: yes if i pass directly pixel then transparent color will be passed that is also not working  @RajatN

Comment: In My case it is working fine i don't know why it is not working in your case
I am putting complete code in answer check if by mistakenly you are doing any mistake